# Adding Pyjwt to aws lambda function layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

i'm trying to add Pyjwt library to aws lambda function layer but still have the same error no module named 'jwt'

I used cloudshell to install pyjwt in virtual env and zip it and upload in an s3 bucket then added it as a layer in my lambda function and still have the same error "no module named jwt"

Answer (score 1):

I've also spent some time troubleshooting issues with lambda layers. I've gotten them working using the following guidelines:

1. Make sure the layer's "compatible runtimes" match that of the package you installed
2. I've found that installing the package into a folder called "python" (in my case I was using a python function) and ziping the "python" folder and its contents

Hope this helps as I've spent plenty of time on lambda layers issues

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience . i made sure the layer's compatible runtimes match but got the same error :/